# Подскажите с запросом в MySQL для переноса данных из таблицы в таблицу

Tags: mysql, запрос

Подскажите, как написать правильно запрос для переноса данных из таблицы b_catalog_store_product в таблицу b_catalog_product из поля AMOUNT в QUANTITY ориентируясь по PRODUCT_ID и ID
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Для обновления всех записей

```
UPDATE b_catalog_product p
SET p.quantity = (SELECT amount
                  FROM b_catalog_store_product s
                  WHERE p.id = s.product_id)
```

Для изменения только одной записи надо делать так

```
UPDATE b_catalog_product p
SET p.quantity = (SELECT amount
                  FROM b_catalog_store_product s
                  WHERE p.id = s.product_id)
WHERE p.id = 1234
```

Для изменения по условию, такой вариант для условия в таблице `b_catalog_store_product`

```
UPDATE b_catalog_product p
SET p.quantity = (SELECT amount
                  FROM b_catalog_store_product s
                  WHERE p.id = s.product_id)
WHERE p.id IN (SELECT product_id
               FROM b_catalog_store_product 
               WHERE amount > 0)
```

Для изменения по условию, такой вариант для условия в таблице `b_catalog_product`

```
UPDATE b_catalog_product p
SET p.quantity = (SELECT amount
                  FROM b_catalog_store_product s
                  WHERE p.id = s.product_id)
WHERE p.quantity > 0
```

Comment: Что-то не так  #1242 - Подзапрос возвращает более одной записи

Comment: Условие добавте. Так вы пытаетесь всю таблицу изменить.

Comment: Так мне и нужно это =) Хотелось бы взять все значения из Amount(их 4700 штук) и подставить в поле  QUANTITY в другой таблице. А маяк для того, что бы значения подставлялись в правильную строку ID и Product_ID так как они одинаковые в обоих таблицах

Comment: Первый запрос затронет все записи в таблице. Второй только одну. Какое условие выборки у вас?? Например ```amount > 0``` ??

Comment: Интересный вариант а >= 0 возможно использовать? грубо говоря amount от 0 до бесконечности

Comment: Да вы можете так сделать.